# Simple GET request from Parse.com gives 401

Tags: python, parse-platform

I have signed up to Parse.com as I was thinking of using it to store data for an app I am making.

I've created a simple class called Player and I have added a player directly via the Parse.com website.

I'm trying to write some python to query Parse.com to return my Player, but I get a response that says: `{"error":"unauthorized"}`

I'm a bit confused about this. Here is my code:

```
import json, httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)

conn.connect()

conn.request('GET', '/1/classes/Player', json.dumps({"X-Parse-Application-id":"APP ID", "X-Parse-REST-API-Key":"REST KEY", "Content-Type":"application/json"}))

print conn.getresponse().read()

conn.close()
```

If anyone could give me any pointers I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You're sending headers as (json) body. `HTTPConnection.request(method, url[, body[, headers]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied directly from the REST API [queries](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries) documentation:

```
import json, httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/Player', '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

The app id and key should be passed as headers via the 4th argument to `connection.request` (not the 3rd as in your code). They are *not* JSON encoded. Note the empty string (`''`) being passed in the 3rd argument as the body of the request.

Alternatively, use the `requests` module:

```
import requests

headers = {"X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
           "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}"}
r = requests.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Player', headers=headers)
result = r.json()
```